# Add text label in the top-left of a TableForm

Tags: output-formatting, list-manipulation, headers-footers

I have a function that should give a multiplication table for an integer input:

```
TableForm[Outer[Times, Range[#], Range[#]], TableHeadings -> Automatic]&
```

But, this doesn't display an `x` in the top-left header cell, like I want. Is there an easy way to put text in that empty label spot? I want the result to look like this (taken from [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10%20multiplication%20table)):

[image: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10+multiplication+table]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `Grid`

```
n = 10;
r = Range @ n;

Grid[
 Join[{Join[{"x"}, r]}, Flatten /@ Transpose[{r, Outer[Times, r, r]}]],
 Alignment -> Right,
 Background -> {{1 -> LightGray}, {1 -> LightGray}, {1, 1} -> None},
 Dividers -> {{2 -> True}, {2 -> True}},
 ItemStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 16],
 Frame -> True,
 Spacings -> {1.5, 1.5}]
```

[image]

Or, to show all dividers, `Dividers -> All`